# Como redondear decimales de porcentaje en GGPLOT2 en una gráfica de barras segmentada?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hola amigos tengo un problema con una gráfica de barras de porcentaje segmentada que cree, quiero que solo me muestre dos decimales pero le agrego el accuracy `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.01))` y no funciona, ya he seguido algunas recomendaciones que vi en internet como:
`scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1L))`
`scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 3L))`
pero no encuentro una solución.

Anexo imagen de la gráfica:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSzEO.jpg

anexo mi código

````
ggplot(df, aes(x=TIPO ,  group=SEXO)) + 
   geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +
   geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop..),
                  y= ..prop..), stat= "count", vjust = -.03) +
   facet_grid(~SEXO) +
   scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 0.01))+ labs(x="Sexo", y="Porcentaje", title="Sexo por tipo", fill="Tipo") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 34, hjust = 0.85))```
````

Answer (score 0):

Como que te falta agregar el nombre de la columna que va en el eje y, dentro del `percent()`

````
ggplot(df, aes(x=TIPO ,  group=SEXO)) + 
   geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +
   geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop..),
                  y= ..prop..), stat= "count", vjust = -.03) +
   facet_grid(~SEXO) +
   scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent(...prop..., accuracy = 0.01))+ labs(x="Sexo", y="Porcentaje", title="Sexo por tipo", fill="Tipo") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 34, hjust = 0.85))```
````

Answer (score 0):

Para controlar el numero de decimales en los porcentajes que están por encima de las barras de la gráfica se debe agregar a esta parte del código el accuracy como se ve a continuación:  `geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop.., accuracy = 0.01)`

Es decir el código quedaría asi:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=TIPO ,  group=SEXO)) + 
   geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +
   geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop.., accuracy = 0.01), stat= "count", vjust = -.03) +
   facet_grid(~SEXO) +
   scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent(...prop..., accuracy = 0.01))+ labs(x="Sexo", y="Porcentaje", title="Sexo por tipo", fill="Tipo") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 34, hjust = 0.85))
```

Es importante resaltar que el accuracy que está en esta linea de codigo

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent(...prop..., accuracy = 0.01))
```

va a modificar el numero de decimales que están en el eje de las y